# Dynamic GeoJSON on Cesium

Tags: geoserver, geojson, cesium, real-time, czml

I am trying to visualize live data that is updated every 5 seconds coming from a GeoJSON layer served by GeoServer.

What is the best way to do this on Cesium?

I saw that the GeoJsonDatasources in Cesium is intended only for static data, does this mean I have to convert my GeoJSON to CZML to be able to use the CzmlDataSource or it's a better choice to build a custom datasource and update the entities using the GeoJSON layer that is being served by GeoServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CZML works best when you know multiple points in time all at once, for example if you have received telemetry for a flight path, or have a mission plan set in the future, and you have a set of time-tagged geo locations that can be combined into a single CZML stream.

But, if you're stuck just polling for live data every so often, then you really just have a set of "static" points (frequently updated ones, perhaps, but not ones that have a time-ordered list of locations).  In that case, CZML can't buy you much, and you're probably just as well polling for GeoJSON.